# Moving database from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I want to move my my database of a SQL Server 2008 to a SQL Server 2005 Express on another machine. Is this possible? How should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "built-in" way to move a database from a newer SQL Server version to an older version.

The only way that I know if is to use SQL Server 2008's ["Generate Script" wizard](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-script-data-with-generate-script-wizard.aspx) to script your whole database (tables **and** data) and execute these scripts on the SQL Server 2005 to insert the data there.

*(Moving a database from a older SQL Server version to an newer version would be easier - just take a backup and restore, SQL Server automatically converts it to the new version)*

Comment: For the data: if both instances are "reachable" - you can use the Data Import/Export wizard to just copy data from one database to the other

Comment: @user1565210: If my answer was helpful to you, it would be nice if you  [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it.

Comment: @marc_s: you're right, I didn't think of this. If it's a lot of data, just scripting the empty tables and then doing `insert into NewServer.NewDB.dbo.table1 select * from OldServer.OldDB.dbo.table1` is easier to do IMO.